# How to change style of the x-axis?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

This first picture is a recent line graph I created.

[image: First Picture]

Notice how the x-axis has the year showing multiple times unlike the second line graph below. Is there a way to have the year show only once? If there isn't a quick and easy way, I'll probably create multiple text boxes.

Secondly, How can I keep the gridline from going *over* the area underneath the line?

[image: Second Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eliminate the repetitive years, simply delete the repeated values that the axis labels draw from.  So, instead of

[image: original layout]

use

[image: correct layout]

and the labels will follow.  For best effect, make sure that years are above quarters and keep the first Year value, or you'll get this:

[image: not this]

which will look like this:

[image: or this]

You really shouldn't use text boxes-they're nothing but a formatting nightmare.

Also, your other question is a different question, so you should make it it's own.  It's pretty interesting, because I can't get my gridlines to print over the fill.  Check your fill transparency settings-maybe you've got transparency in there?  Here's the above image with a 33% transparency:

[image: transparency]

Comment: Thank you! I was able to solve the second question through Design > Quick Layout and adjusting my chart from there.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your second question you expect there are no lines between axis labels `Q1`, `Q2` and so on. If so this is an option `Tick marks` as on the graphs.
[image: Tick_marks][image: Area_chart]